# Static link MySQL X DevAPI in Visual Studio Project

Tags: c++, mysql, linker, static-libraries, mysql-connector

I want to use MySQL X DevApi (C++ Connector) and after doing everything that documentation says, I'm still unable to build my project.

What I done in project properties (Release x64):

```
C/C++ => General => Additional Include directoris => Added C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\include

C/C++ => Preprocessor => Preprocessor Definitions => Added STATIC_CONCPP

C/C++ => Code Generation => Runtime Library => Picked Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)

Linker => General => Additional Library Directories => Added C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\lib64\vs14

Linker => Input => Additional Dependiencies => Added mysqlcppconn8-static.lib
```

and with that, I'm still getting these errors (my project is called `doesItWork`):

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol DnsFree  doesItWork  C:\Users\Robert\source\repos\doesItWork\doesItWork\mysqlcppconn8-static.lib(socket_detail.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol DnsQuery_A   doesItWork  C:\Users\Robert\source\repos\doesItWork\doesItWork\mysqlcppconn8-static.lib(socket_detail.obj)  1   
Error   LNK1120 2 unresolved externals  doesItWork  C:\Users\Robert\source\repos\doesItWork\x64\Release\doesItWork.exe  1
```

As those are comming from `socket_detail.obj` I tried adding `libcrypto.lib` and `libssl.lib` as documentation sometimes mentions (from `C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\lib64\vs14`) but error still appears.

I'm using `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019` and have my project and "`Oracle Connector`" both for `x64 Release`.

For now my code looks like this (does nothing essentially):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace mysqlx;

int main()
{
    Session sess("localhost", 33060, "root", "root");
    Schema db = sess.getSchema("mytestdb");
    cout << "hey!" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to add `Dnsapi.lib`.

Comment: Hey I'm having the exact same issue. Where is Dnsapi.lib located? It's not in the \lib64\vs14 folder